# Issue with Lambda function: Invalid type for parameter

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm writing an AWS Lambda function in Python and have an issue. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
containerInstances = listContainerInstances['containerInstanceArns'][j]

containerInstancesDetails = ecs.describe_container_instances(cluster=cluster, containerInstances=containerInstances)
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid type for parameter containerInstances, value: arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:11111111111:container-instance/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>: ParamValidationError
```

Anyone knows how the fix this issue? Do i need to convert from unicode to list? If so, how? I tried several things which didn't help.

Please advise.

Comment: What happens if you remove the final `[j]` on the first line ? According to the error msg, `containerInstances` should be a tuple or a list, but you only pick up one item at index 'j', instead of the whole list.

Comment: I will get the whole list, While i want the result of just one of them. I'm able to use this specific command in CLI, which gives me the expected result. Please see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-container-instances.html (see their example). However, The same command doesn't work well in their SDK, Which expecting to a tulip or a list. See here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know AWS Lambda, but given @sciroccorics's hint, and assuming it works like you would expect Python to work, all you need to do is ensure that `containerInstances` is a list:

```
containerInstances = [listContainerInstances['containerInstanceArns'][j]]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome! So simple :-)